# Why does mortgage servicer refuse to correct prior statements?

Tags: united-states, mortgage

I noticed a mistake in classification in a statement where [additional principal was split into principal and interest](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/155865/additional-principal-payment-split-between-interest-and-principal). When I asked the servicer to correct that statement and all others, they refused and said that statements after that would be corrected.

Why is this? Isn't a statement an official document?

I asked another question prior to this [about using statements as proof](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/154458/do-paperless-mortgage-statements-put-one-at-risk) when the servicer changes and so I am irate that they don't want to change this.

Is there any recourse I have to them fixing the numbers?

**EDIT:**

I did specify it correctly. There is an entry that says "additional principal" no other wording was there. It wasn't "additional payment".

Moreover, they did agree that it was applied to principal and that it wouldn't be to interest. They admitted the error but didn't want to correct the prior statements.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you failed to specify that the additional funds were intended as additional principal. In that case, it was probably applied exactly as shown, as prepayment toward both rather than as principal.

If so, the statement is correct; they just didn't do what you intended. There is nothing to correct. Sorry about the bad news.

Hopefully they now understand your intent -- though I would recommend stating it explicitly every time! -- so future payments could be credited as you intend. Check and correct them IMMEDIATELY if it isn't.

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: Have they given you a new statement that correctly reflects the decreased principal? If so, you don't need the corrected old statements. If your current statement does *not* show reduced principal, then they haven't agreed that this was your intent, and you need to continue beating on them, perhaps with community advocates or lawyers if it's worth that much effort -- or grumble and give up.

Comment: I was calculating things in a spreadsheet and stopped when I saw the error. I will continue with the calculations to see what the amount should show up in the latest one.